Minimal cost to set the springs to the same length
I am working on the following task:
You are given a sorted collection of springs. Each of them has been produced in certain dimensions, and each stretching, or compression, requires quite a bit of effort.
It takes 1 unit of effort to lengthen or shorten a spring that has not yet been moved by a centimeter. Each successive stretch, or compression, of the same spring requires an additional 1 unit of effort. More precisely, if you want to lengthen a spring by D centimeters, he will exert himself by 1,2,…,D successive units of effort.
Your task is to answer q queries about how much minimal effort it would cost to set the k-shortest springs to the same length.
Constraints: N,Q <= 106, xi <= 109
Input:
N, Q 
x1, x2, x3, ...
q1, q2, q3, ...
N - number of springs
xi - length of i-th spring (Note that xi <= xi+1)
qi - how many springs should be set to the same length in i-th question
Output:
Answers to questions - minimal effort it would cost to set the k-shortest springs to the same length. Because answer may be large print it modulo 10^9+7.
My solution attempt:
I discovered that the minimal effort would be achieved when the springs are set to the average length of the springs. However in this approach complexity of algorithm is O(n*q) which is too slow for given constraints.
How can I solve this faster?
In my brutal approach I calculate the average length of the springs and then linearly calculate the cost for every spring. It is too slow for N,Q <= 106 but is enough for n,q <= 103.

The total effort for a spring with starting length x and target length v is proportional to (x-v)2.
For a bunch of N springs, Sum[(xi-v)2] = Sum[xi2] - 2v*Sum[xi] +Nv2
Note that the summations do not depend on the target length at all, so you can just precalculate Sum[xi2] and Sum[xi] for all the prefixes of your array in O(n) time.
Then for each query, you can look up the appropriate sums and calculate the minimum cost for any v in O(1) time, giving O(n+q) all together.
As you have already determined, the minimum effort target length is the average spring length Sum[xi]/N.  That's not always going to be an integer, so just try the 2 integers on either side of it.

Applying a modulus to the answer is an exercise left to the reader.

Although if you really want to apply it to the lengths, then you can do that by keeping track of the largest length gap and deciding whether or not it would be better to add 10^9+7 to the lengths preceding it.

Thanks for help. I didn't think the solution would be so simple and I seamlessly tried doing O(q*log(n)) solution.

You're welcome.  Note that this is a traditional trick for calculating a running variance or least-squared-error cost, or with a little modification, doing the same on a sliding window.  Those are things you may actually need in real life, so it's a good trick to know.

Can we do O(1) space if we order the queries and add the updates based on the number of updated elements and their sum? Haven’t worked through to the end but I think so.

@גלעדברקן If you order the queries, then you don't need to remember any sums... but you need to remember all the query results so you can output in the correct order.  Not O(1) space, then.

Heh, good point!
